# Is there any function that can allow auto scheduling of posts using ckeditor in a website builth from php scratch?

Tags: php, cron, ckeditor, scheduled-tasks

**I have a php website built from scratch, it has a ckeditor plugin for adding posts and videos to the website.**

So, i'll like to know if there's a way to add scheduling post feature on Ckeditor, just like wordpress has. I just set a date and time for the post to go live, then the system handles everything for me automatically.

Comment: CKEditor is purely a front-end editor, it wouldn't be logical to build such a feature into that directly - it has no knowledge of what happens to the data after you submit it to the server. I suggest, if your ckeditor is part of a form, that you add an additional field in there so the user can specify when they want the post to go live. You can then save that info in your database alongside the post itself. And then whatever function you have for displaying will take account of that date when selecting which posts to display.

Comment: A "future date" for a post to go live is a good idea. The "system" part just needs to include relevant posts on a condition such as `postDate >= curDate`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.